# How might one develop a program like FRAPS?

Tags: c++

I would like to make a program to capture video.

- What is the best way to capture video?
- I know C++ and I'm learning assembly. I found in my assembly book that I can get data from the video card. Would that be the best way?
- I know FRAPS hooks into programs, but I would like my program to take video of the entire screen.

I would like something something fast, with low memory usage if possible. A requirement is that the program must be usable on other computers, despite dissimilar hardware.

Comment: What platform? Graphics are inherently platform dependant. EDIT: This was a very poorly written question. I have modified it to be slightly more readable. In the future though, if you're too lazy to press the shift key than several are going to be too lazy to help answer a question. Particularly when the question stinks of PLZ_SEND_THE_CODEZ.

Comment: Your last two sentences make it seem like you want us to send you the code. Are you looking for an explanation of *how* to do it or do you just want a library that does this?

Comment: @musicfreak: Keep in mind the last two sentences are heavily filtered by two editors.

Comment: -.- i don't want code i was asking what would work the best :\

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way Fraps works, it's impossible to capture the entire screen (unless you're running a full-screen DirectX application, of course). You're apparently trying to emulate the functionality of [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/), more so than Fraps.

CamStudio is open-source ([here is the SorceForge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/camstudio/)) so perhaps you could start by studying the source code? I would wager that it's not really for beginners, however.

Answer (score 2):

Capturing an entire screen is simple, in short you get a desktop handle (GetWindowHandle(0)) and BitBlt() it to your bitmap.

Now you need to encode it to video, potentially full HD or more, in real time, using the best possible compression, ideally lossless because of text on the screen and vector graphics nature of traditional desktops. I don't know any good custom codec for such requirements so would recommend to use traditional h.264 and tune tradeoff between quality and performance. FFMPEG is probably the most popular library for this, just check license of h.264 encoding.

Comment: what about an permanent overlay on top of the screen you want to capture? Like the Show FPS option in fraps?

Comment: But why only windows? Am I not able to use h.264 on Linux for instance? I mean.. there should be a equally easy way of getting desktop handle on Linux also? And in what language would you write it? C or C++?

Comment: @Veske: I just haven't done something like this on Linux so I cannot help you here. C or C++? Actually it doesn't matter here, use what you know better.